# Как вытащить из values значения в string формате?

Tags: python, словари, google-spreadsheet

```py
    from pprint import pprint
    import httplib2
    import apiclient.discovery
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import config
    
    CREDENTIALS_FILE = config.settings['CREDS']
    spreadsheet_id = config.settings['URL_SHEETS']
    
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        CREDENTIALS_FILE,
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth)
    
    # Пример чтения файла
    def FindOrder(order_range):
        values = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
            range = f'B{order_range}:J{order_range}',
            majorDimension='ROWS'
        ).execute()
        return values
    pprint(FindOrder(4))
```

вывод:

```
{'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
             'range': 'Base!B4:J4',
             'values': [['271904',
                         'Иванов Сергей Петрович',
                         't.me/ser_iv',
                         'СПб',
                         'Nike Air Force 1 `07 (white) (10,5 US)',
                         'FALSE',
                         'Буренков Г.В.',
                         '28.09.2023',
                         '-']]}
```

Мне нужно вытащить только значения values, например, Буренков Г.В

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто обратитесь к нужному индексу.

```py
data = {'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
        'range': 'Base!B4:J4',
        'values': [['271904',
                    'Иванов Сергей Петрович',
                    't.me/ser_iv',
                    'СПб',
                    'Nike Air Force 1 `07 (white) (10,5 US)',
                    'FALSE',
                    'Буренков Г.В.',
                    '28.09.2023',
                    '-']]}

value = data['values'][0][6] #туть
print(value)
```

Вывод:
`Буренков Г.В.`

Comment: спасибо,  а как вообще называется такой тип данных?

Comment: @skv0r это JSON объект с ключами и значениями, где один из значений - это вложенный список в формате списка списков

Comment: А на верхнем уровне тут словарь.